# How do I use the MariaDB Connector/J?

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc, jar, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to a database in Java. My database is MariaDB so I'd prefer to use the MariaDB connector. I am using Gradle to produce a jar that is then ran in a spigot minecraft server.

When connecting to the DB I use `con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL);` where `jdbcURL == "jdbc:mariadb://playerdata:1234@127.0.0.1:3306/playerdata"`.

I get the error `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://playerdata:1234@127.0.0.1:3306/playerdata`.

When replacing `mariadb` with `mysql` in the JDBC URL it works as expected. It's clear that the MariaDB connector is not being added to the classpath when running, so I've inspected the jar and it only contains my own compiled source. In attempt to fix this, I've tried creating a "fat" jar with the gradle plugin "shadow". While now it appears that the connector's compiled java is added to the jar, and `Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");` does not throw an exception, I still get the same `SQLException` when trying to connect to JDBC URLs starting with `jdbc:mariadb://`.

Here is a snippet of my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
}
...
dependencies {
...
    runtimeClasspath 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.0.3'
    shadow 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.0.3'
}
```

At runtime, while it is possible, I would really prefer not changing JVM arguments to modify the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly strange. I changed my JDBC URL to `jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/playerdata?user=playerdata&password=1234`, and it works. Reverting this change back to `jdbc:mariadb://playerdata:1234@127.0.0.1:3306/playerdata` yields a different error `java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect port value : 1234@127.0.0.1`. I am certain that I changed nothing else, but who am I to complain?